# spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix, setting the hystrix origin id

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, hystrix, turbine

I'm using the spring-cloud-samples/customer-stores example and have it working as described (specifically using 1.1.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT)

It appears that when things stream to hystrix, it attaches an origin object such as the following:

```
"origin": {
  "host": "192.168.60.100",
  "port": 9000,
  "serviceId": "customers",
  "id": "customers:mysql:9000"
}
```

Specifically, it looks like the "id" is being created from `serviceId`:`spring.profiles.active`:`server.port`

This works just fine when you have several distinct combinations of this that can be used, however, when I'm running several services either on different ips with the same `server.port` or am running several docker containers with the same `server.port`, the turbine aggregation gets garbled & makes no sense, since the data is writing all over itself.

I'm wondering if there is a specific way in Spring that we can specifically affect the value of that id in our setup.

Comment: So... Looks like this is being determined in the class `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.stream.HystrixStreamTask`.  In the call to `addServiceData()`, it uses the Autowired _ApplicationContext_ and does a getId().  Question now seems to be - Can we modify the ApplicationContext id used by SpringBoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply setting the `hystrix.stream.queue.send-id=false` as described by @spencergibb in the post on github: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/740 solves the problem.